# How to solve following partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)u(t,a,x)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(t,a,x)-[\mu+\gamma(a)]u(t,a,x)$

$t>0,a>0,x\in[l_1,l_2]$

where

$u_x(t,a,l_1)=u_x(t,a,l_2)=0\  for \  all\ t>0\ and\  a>0$

$u(t,0,x)=S(t,x)\int_0^{\infty}\beta(a)u(t,a,x)da$

$u(0,a,x)=\phi(x)$

Comment: Why do you think it is one-dimensional?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions should be written in such a way that they make sense even without reading their titles.

Comment: Oh,sorry,it isn't one-dimensional.

Comment: Since I can not tell from your question what you tried, where you got stuck and how familiar you are in general  with PDEs, I don't really have enough information for a full answer. So here is a small hint: make an Ansatz with trigonometric functions for the $x$-domain similar to the Possoin equation and them solve the remaining system of transport equations.